# Apple inHouse app distribution for company with less than 100 employess

Tags: ios, iphone

What are the option to distribute a IOS app inhouse. For "Apple Developer Enterprise Program" , company should have more than 100 employees. If a company with less than 100 employees wants to distribute the app internally only to employees what can be the option."Apple Developer Program" cannot be used to distribute inHouse Apps. As app is only for employess, so it will be distributed from internal company website and cannot be distributed from App Store.

Comment: Your best option is to register for Apple Business Manager.  You can then create a custom app in App Store connect and make it available to your own organisation in Apple Business Manager. Watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10667 And https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304

Answer (score 0):

Apple has [lengthy document called "Distribute proprietary in-house apps to Apple devices"](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/distribute-proprietary-in-house-apps-depce7cefc4d/web) listing your options. If you want to go with Mobile Device Management (the most flexible solution), you need to search for an MDM solution as Apple does not provide one. However, Apple has [some notes about how to select an MDM solution](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/choose-an-mdm-solution-dep1d7afa557/web).

Comment: That document is for the distribution of enterprise signed apps, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Paulw11: Where does it say it must be enterprise signed? I work for a small company and we do what's outlined in the document using Ad-Hoc signing and MDM.

Comment: The process described in the document is the enterprise distribution process. It even mentions the enterprise program. I guess you could use ad hoc signing but that is a significant management burden; every time someone gets a new phone you need to register the device, update the provisioning profile and rebuild the app. Depending on the number of devices you can also exceed the 100 device limit. Ad hoc builds also expire. A custom app is a much better solution.